# Is a file a directory or a normal file?

Tags: java, file

I would like to write a program (in Java), which will go through the file system and tell whether the file is a directory or a normal file.

How would you suggest doing so?

Comment: This functionality is already built into the java language

Answer (score 3):

The [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class has built-in methods [`isFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29) and [`isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29).

```
File fp = new File("path.txt");
System.out.println(fp.isFile()?"Is a File":"Is NOT a File");
System.out.println(fp.isDirectory()?"Is a Directory":"Is NOT a Directory");
```

Answer (score 2):

[`File` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) can help you.

[`.isFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29), [`.isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29)

Example:

```
String path = "path here";
new File(path).isFile();
```

isFile returns true if it's a file. Too .isDirectory if it's a directory.

Anyway, in File class you can find more userful methods just read the documentation.

To list every file/directory in a path, [`.list()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29), [`.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) should do what you want.

Important, .list returns an array of Strings (just the names of the files) example:

```
String path = "";
File file = new File(path); // Here we create the File object to work with the directory/file 
String[] files = file.list(); // .list returns the name of every file/directory inside the path

for(String fname : files)
{
    System.out.print(fname + " ");
}
```

Use [`.listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) if you need to use a method from [`File class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), like you asked now you can use [`.isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29) and [`.isFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29)

```
String path = "";
File file = new File(path);
File[] files = file.listFiles();

for(File fname : files)
{
    if (fname.isDirectory())
    {
        System.out.println(fname.getName() + " is a directory.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(fname.getName() + " is a file.");   
    }
}
```

Use .list if you need to get the names of the files inside a path and stop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what are you asking. Maybe the method `File.isFile` ?